# (geo)django's dwithin-filter giving error whereas ST_DWithin from postgres works

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm using geodjango and I want to filter rows from a table based on distance:

```
geom = models.MultiLineStringField()
```

When I use geodjango like so:

```
geo_objects.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(pnt, D(km=10)))
```

where pnt is 'POINT (-73.5666999999996136 45.5000000000000213)'

Geodjango gives me:

```
*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Join on field 'geom' not permitted. Did you misspell 'dwithin' for the lookup type?
```

On the other hand, doing the same thing (as far as I understand) directly from the postgres command line returns sensible results:

```
select * from geo_objects
WHERE ST_DWithin(geo_objects.geom, 'POINT(-73.5665 45.5000)', 122222, false)
```

works perfectly well.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats the answer:
in order to perform geometric queries, you need a geomanager.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geomanager